# How can I turn every row with a certain index into two others?

Tags: r, format

I've got this dataset: [link](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/owid/covid-19-data/master/public/data/owid-covid-data.csv). I'm making a choropleth out of it, but there are certain names that do not match with the `world` data frame (from `mapproj`, converted with `map_data` from `ggplot2`). One of them is `Trindad and Tobago`, which I want to replace with two (or four if there are two matches; or six...) other rows, identical to the original except for this detail – the name. One should be named `Trindad` and the other, `Tobago`.

I think there's probably some function (if it were an entire row, I'd use `separate_rows()` from `tidyr`) that sounds like this: `function_name("Trindad and Tobago", sep = " and ")`, but I don't know it.

These are the packages I loaded additionally (it's best if these packages are used instead of others, or at least something in `tidyverse`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(readr)
library(mapproj)
```

I realise that the way I'm asking this isn't very clear, so if I can help in any way...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you can create a tibble with the names of countries that you want to seperate (called **new_names_tbl** here) you can join it onto your **covid_data**:

```
library(tibble)
library(tidyr)


covid_data <- tibble::tribble(
  ~location, ~cases,
  "Afghanistan",  12,
  "USA", 34,
  "Trindidad and Tobago", 45
)



new_names_tbl <- tibble::tribble(
  ~location, ~new_names_variable,
  "Trindidad and Tobago", "Trinidad",
  "Trindidad and Tobago", "Tobago"
  
)

covid_data %>% 
  left_join(new_names_tbl, by = c("location" = "location")) %>% 
  mutate(location = case_when(is.na(new_names_variable) ~ location, TRUE ~ new_names_variable)) %>%
  select(-new_names_variable)
```

Here I explicitly stated that **coid_data** and **new_names_tbl** are to be joined by the variables *location*.
This should do the trick!